# Why Matplotlib 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I just discovered that Matplotlib 3.0 has been released. As the 2.0 release is still fresh in my memory (well, it's about one and a half year ago) and the fact that we are still just at 2.2, I wonder what made the developers opt for an increase to the major version number? The [docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html) does not seem to hint at an explanation.

#### Edit

Since this question has been flagged as being "primarily opinion-based", let me add that I would like a link to some official explanation by the Matplotlib developers.

Comment: Exactly the same thoughts here, but I think it's probably off-topic for SO. Join [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) :)

Comment: Matplotlib 3 only supports python 3.

Comment: Same thoughts here too. You are absolutely right. However this could be flagged as off-topic.

Comment: I edited the answer with a link to some "official" document, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 12):

It is true that matplotlib 3.0 does not provide many new features that would usually require a major version number change.

The main point of version 3.0 is that it [is python 3 only](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/api/api_changes.html#api-changes-for-3-0-0).

Dropping python 2.7 constitutes an API change and thus required a major version bump. While for people using python 3 anyways this API change may seem rather minor, people using python 2 will care a lot.

The step to go to python 3 only allowed the developpers to get rid of all the code that was needed to maintain compatibility between python 2 and python 3. Most of this is not seen from the outside, but cleaning up the codebase will now allow to move forward with new features a bit quicker. Also bugfixing is simplified a good bit, since no workarounds for python2/3 are needed any more.
More new features are to expected for the first minor version 3.1.

To summarize we now have

- matplotlib 2.2.x which still supports python 2.7 and which will receive bugfixes until the official python 2 development ends in 2020, but which will not contain any more new features.
- matplotlib 3.x which will be continuously developped from now on and supports python 3.5 or greater.

Because the question asks for some "official" statement, [this mailing list entry](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/matplotlib-devel/2016-May/000374.html) initiated the versioning, which was then resceduled in [this message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/matplotlib-devel/2017-October/000892.html). (note that in contrast to those, python 3.5 is still supported in matplotlib 3.0)